# Update a value from linq query

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, listobject

I am in the middle of an api integration and i have to update something from linq query.

```
 var t = availabilityRs.hotels.hotels.Select(c => c.rooms.Select(h => 
                       h.rates.Select(y => { y.net = y.net*2;return y; })) ).ToList();
```

This is the query i wrote.

I want to update the net in the end of the object tree and assign it to var t. But this query doesn't update it. I wanna know what's wrong with this code.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Objects? What is the type of `availabilityRs`?

Comment: LINQ to objects. availabilityRs is an object of AvailabilityRs model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thank you for the help. **Kara** your answer isn't the exact answer for my question but it was a big help to me to form my answer. Thanks alot!
This is my answer..

```
    availabilityRs.hotels.hotels.ToList().ForEach
        (c => c.rooms.ToList().ForEach
        (h => h.rates.ForEach
        (f => f.net = (int)Math.Round((f.net * rates), 0))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Select retrieves some values. What you want to do is a ForEach.

```
var tmp = availabilityRs.hotels.hotels.Select(c => c.rooms.Select(h => h.rates.ToList();
tmp.ForEach(y => y.net *= 2);
```

Comment: `List.Foreach()` returns `void` - you can't apply `ToList()` to it.